# Double collision of prefab in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection, 2d-games

I would like that when two spheres (prefab) meet they disappear and form a square, but 2 are formed

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class circle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject square;
    Vector3 pos;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if(collision.gameObject.name == this.gameObject.name)  {
            pos = transform.position;
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Instantiate(square, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

}
```

I tried with for and while loops and with a variable but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: correct, both of them will run the same code.

Comment: I would like the two circles to disappear and one square to appear instead of two

Comment: then you need to decide on a method of that, as both items with the same script will do the same logic

Answer (score 0):

The reason 2 squares are spawned is because both objects are spawning the square.
To fix this, add a boolean to the class to indicate if merging already happened.
Before merging, check that boolean to see if merging has already been handled.
If it hasn't been merged yet, set merged to true and destroy both objects.

```
public class Circle : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isMerged;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) 
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent<Circle>(out var otherCircle) &&
            collision.gameObject.name == this.gameObject.name &&
            otherCircle.isMerged == false)
        {
            isMerged = true;
            Instantiate(square, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```